# How can I sequentially number rows from a query result?

Tags: php, foreach

I have a MySQL table:

```
id    name    address    phone number
16    ek      kathmandu    3890
18    rk      New york     29304
20    ki      Boston       09683
```

Now I want to print this list in an HTML table like

```
id     name    address     phonenumber
1     ek      kathmandu    3890
2     rk      New york     29304
3     ki      Boston       09683
```

using logic

```
**id     name    address     phonenumber**
<?php foreach ($list as $namelist){?>
  $namelist->id   $namelist->name  $namelist->address  $namelist->phone number   
<?php}?>
```

As we can see, `$namelist->id` inside `foreach` will give direct ID from table, but I want 1 2 3 in the ID. Using `for` loop or other loop, I did it, but it didn't work out. How can I sequentially number rows?

Comment: Why not just modify the MySQL query to only return rows with an id of less than 4?

Comment: Because that wouldn't be the desired effect.

Comment: mysql does not have have the concept of a row number in the result set like some database vendors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean something like:

```
<?php
  $i = 0;
?>
<?php 
    foreach ($list as $namelist){
      ...
      $i++; //$i will increment with each iteration of foreach
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

So just declare this outside the loop:

```
$i = 0;
```

and then inside the loop, before displaying anything, iterate it:

```
$i++;
```

and then display it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a variable.

If you want to stick with your foreach, it can be something like this

```
<?php    
        $counter = 1;
             foreach ($list as $namelist){
             echo '<tr>';
             echo '<td>' +  $counter + '</td>';
             echo '<td>' +  $namelist->name + '</td>';
             echo '<td>' +  $namelist->address + '</td>';
             echo '<td>' +  $namelist->phone number + '</td>';
             echo '</tr>';         
              $counter++;
       }
?>
```

or in for loop

```
for($i=1; $i<=$numofrows; $i++){

 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>' +  $counter + '</td>';
 echo '<td>' +  $namelist->name + '</td>';
 echo '<td>' +  $namelist->address + '</td>';
 echo '<td>' +  $namelist->phone number + '</td>';
 echo '</tr>';      

}
```